# Why doesnt this loop work?

Tags: java

```
for(int i=0; i<=years; i++; finall=money+returnn;)

{
      System.out.println(finall);
}
```

for some reason netbeans says that I need a ")" in there somewhere? I don't know what's wrong

Comment: You've got two extra `;` in there. There may only be 2.

Comment: For loop only takes 3 statements not 4

Comment: Because that's not a valid declaration of a `for` loop

Comment: @JoachimSauer For all who make downvote to my answer , first i see the first error in  the OP'question , i mean the `;` so i wrote it , and trying to see the wrong but i have problem in my browser , so who say to me the "Harsh" necessary here , excuse me sir we here as a developer not as child to say that to me ,it's clearly have an error in syntax to the beginner , @Makaldeu : sorry i say it in your question

Comment: @Alya'aGamal: I have no problem with you posting that answer, nobody expects everybody to be perfect at all times. But it should not have gotten that many upvotes. People blindly upvoting stuff that *looks* reasonable without checking if it's correct is a problem.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't put a `;` after `finall=money+returnn`. Also your `for` loop has too many parts. It should have 3 (initialization, stop condition, modifier) while you have 4 parts.

If you really want multiple actions in one of those parts though, it is possible by separating them using `,` (so not `;`). In this case though, it would be better to put `finall=money+returnn` inside the loop since it doesn't have anything to do with stopping your loop.

Comment: Also the code setting `finall=...` gets executed at the end of the loop and printed out before the value is calculated. Perhaps it has an initial value from some code that isn't shown here. Perhaps it's just wrong.

Comment: I know it is executed after the print statement for that loop. He can simply put the statement after the print statement. That should have the same result.

Comment: Did you notice what is being printed?

Comment: Yes, but moving that statement inside the loop (after the print) won't change the code semantically, right? So it indeed is wrong anyway if it isn't initialized in the code we can't see, but moving the statement to a place where it is more suitable doesn't make it worse.

Answer (score 7):

You have 3 parts in a `for` loop: initialization, condition and increment. You are defining one more with `finall=money+returnn;`

You can put several incrementations, but separated with commas:

```
for(int i=0; i<=years; i++, finall=money+returnn)
```

but for each loop (different value of i) you will apply all the statements in the last part of the loop.

Comment: You can, howvwer, have multiple parts in the initialization and increment parts, but they are separated by commas. `for(int i=0; i<=years; i++, finall=money+returnn)` should work, though it really looks odd.

Comment: The `finall=...` part isn't incrementing anything and though it can be inside there, it should be with the code in squiggle-braces.

Comment: +1 to Lee: since the `finall` is not part of the condition (or modifying the counter), it *should* be inside the loop body, as a matter of code style.

Comment: You are right, but I wanted to keep the code as close as possible to the original code.